# JavaScript 'undefined' when assigning var to item in string array

Tags: javascript

I'm building a website using Airtable API to scrape data from an Airtable spreadsheet using JS.

I'm running into a fairly simple(?) problem using JavaScript.

I'm putting data from the spreadsheet into a string array `names`. `console.log(names[0])` prints out the string value correctly, but when I try to do something like:

`var test = names[0];`

`console.log(test)`,

It prints out `undefined`

---

Why does this happen?

---

My Code:

```
var names = [];
var locations = [];

//ACCESS AIRTABLE API (GET DATA FROM AIRTABLE SPREADSHEET)
var Airtable = require('airtable');
var base = new Airtable({apiKey: 'keyQ7YUX3SUECVL4C'}).base('appSmUKDnFdEAT1YF');

base('Members').select({
  view: "Grid view"
}).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage) {
    //Fill arrays with data from spreadsheet
  records.forEach(function(record) {
        names.push(record.get('parsedName'));
        locations.push(record.get('parsedLocation'));
  });
  fetchNextPage();

}, function done(err) {
    if (err) { console.error(err); return; }
});
```

Comment: That would suggest that `names` has not been loaded at that point in time.

Comment: Are you loading the array with an asynchronous function? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-undefined-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: @Barmar yes it seems so. Read a little bit about async, promises, callbacks, etc..., but still not really sure how to fix the problem.

Comment: The basic idea is that everything that needs to use the result immediately after it's returned has to be in the callback function. In your case, put `console.log(names[0])` at the end of the `eachPage()` callback function.

Comment: Right before `fetchNextPage()`